# Load data into modal in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I'm trying to populate data into my drop-down option of my modal form but seems not working. The list are not display in my drop-down list. I'm not sure what's wrong with it. Appreciate your advice.
Thanks

Here goes my modal form in view (view_timeline.php)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myTimeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myTimeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>                                            
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myTimeModalLabel">Add New Timeline</h4>
            </div>                                                                                      
        <form role="form" id="TimeForm" action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/addTimeline'; ?>" method= "POST">
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Select Bank *</label>
                <select name="fiid" id="fiid" class="form-control" onChange="fnLoadBank(this)" required=TRUE>
                    <option disabled selected>SELECT BANK</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            // some other item
            </div> <!-- end modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="reset" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" value="submit" form="TimeForm" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Timeline</button>
            </div> <!-- end modal-footer -->
        </form>
```

Here goes my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function fnLoadBank(me) {
        $('.fiid').empty();
        $('.fiid').html('<option disabled selected>SELECT BANK</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>/admin/getBank()',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(dataBank) {
                var str = '';
                if (dataBank) {
                    $.each(dataBank, function(key, row) {
                    str += '<option value="' + row.bankID + '">' + row.bankName + '</option>';
                });
            $('.fiid').append(str);
            }
        }
        });
        }                   
</script>
```

Here goes my admin/getBank controller

```
public function getBank()
{
    $dataBank = $this->model_bank->bank_getAll();
    return $dataBank;
}
```

Here is my controller to load view_timeline.php

```
public function index()
{
    $data['dataBank'] = $this->model_bank->bank_getAll();
    $this->load->view(pages/view_timeline,$data);
}
```

Example of my output

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ BANK ID + BANK NAME + DATE/TIME   + TRANSACTION DETAILS      +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 0001    + BANK A    + 1111/101210 + Transaction 1            +
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
+ 0002    + BANK B    + 1111/103050 + Transaction 2            +
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
+ 0001    + BANK A    + 1111/110105 + Transaction 3            +
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

                                          +ADD MORE TRANSACTION+
```

So when click on ADD MORE TRANSACTION, I need to select the bank (from list of available bank), fill in the details and save (which add to my table without refresh my page). As such, Im using modal to pop-up the form.

Comment: why do you need script? You can do like `<select> <?php foreach($dataBank as $row){ echo '<option value="'.$row->bankID.'">'.$row->bankName.'</option>' ; } ?> </select>` It will be more simple for you.

Comment: i tried.. it doesn't display in my form

Comment: I don't have php+codeigniter environment setup in my laptop so can't produce the code, sorry for that but it is very simple. You must be doing something silly, recheck your code once plus there are so many posts related to your question. Do see them once.

Comment: @shubhamsaini I did check some of the posts but seems like different problem than mine.. I already update my code.. I load dataBank upon view my page but still no data populate in my bank lists. BTW.. thanks for your advice

Comment: Is your Javascript a part of one of your views? Can you please check your URL in your Javascript by viewing the generated HTML in your browser.

Comment: URL pointing to /admin/getBank

Comment: may be you are doing is wrong , because why would you change the select box and get the bank list , you could just load the data or pass the bank list data when popup is load . , why do you want to use ajax for this .  and also seems like you don't want the bank by its id am i right  ?

Comment: Hi Amit.. to be exact.. i want to add data (using form) into my timeline contain banks and its ID as well as transaction details. So there would be listing of  transaction sort by date/time. There would be few banks involve and it could be a repeated transaction..

Comment: so you have already bank list in select box fiid ?

Comment: Bank list still not appear in select box after i make changes like your advice.. :( For normal form in page, i can list it.. but in modal.. it doesn't populate.. i'm not sure whats wrong

Comment: if you want to talk in this matter , then chat with on this URL , hope  i will solve your problem .
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129218/modal-solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129221/discussion-between-julie-and-amit-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) 
{
   fnLoadBank();
});
    function fnLoadBank() 
    {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url("admin/getBank");?>',
        success: function(dataBank) 
        {
            $('#fiid').html(dataBank);
        }
    }
    });
 }                   
</script>

<?php 
public function getBank()
{
    $dataBank = $this->model_bank->bank_getAll();

    $option .= '<option value="" disabled selected >SELECT BANK</option>';
    foreach ($dataBank as $value) {

        $option .= "<option value=".$value['bankID'].">".$value['bankName']."</option>";
    }
    echo $option;

}
?>
```

and try bind this option to your select bank id

```
$('#fiid').html(dataBank);
```

Comment: may be you are doing is wrong , because why would you change the select box and get the bank list , you could just load the data or pass the bank list data when popup is load . , why do you want to use ajax for this .  and also seems like you don't want the bank by its id am i right  ? this my opinion